# Inserting bool into SQL database, c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am making a C# client-server application for my college class.
I have an MS Access database with a table Package, it has some values like 'name', 'dateFrom', 'dateTo', and 2 values called 'internet' and 'telephone' which are YES/NO type

In the program I made a class Package and set internet and telephone as bool type of data. Firstly, is this correct? If value is set as YES/NO in MS Access, am I supposed to set it as bool in C#? this seems logical to me..

Secondly, when I enter SQL command for inserting these values I get an error, I don't know how to send bool values to database

Here is my code

```
command.CommandText = "Insert into Package values ("+p.PackageID+", '"+ p.Name+"', '"+p.DateFrom.ToString()+"', '"+p.DateTo.ToString()+"', "+Convert.ToBoolean(p.Internet.ToString())+", "+Convert.ToBoolean(p.Telephone.ToString())+")";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I tried a lot of things, and this was my last attempt of converting values to be able to insert them.. but it doesn't work..
I always get System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: Please do not use string concatenation for creating SQL commands. Use parameterized statements to pass values in. Your program is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.

Comment: Oh my goodness, [sanitize your inputs](https://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Even if you are just learning, do not shortcut on parameters. You should learn the correct way to do it and avoid the bad habit all together. Check out - [https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter]   Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073357/how-to-insert-bool-into-database

Comment: What is the value of "p.Internet.ToString()" and "p.Telephone.ToString()"? Is it Yes/No or True/False?

Answer (score 3):

For various reasons, you **SHOULD NOT  USE** string concatenation on SQL statements. Use parameters. Try like:

```
command.CommandText = "Insert into Package values (@param1,@param2@param3,@param4,@param5,@param6)";
command.Parameters.Add("@param1",  OleDbType.Integer).Value = p.PackageID;
command.Parameters.Add("@param2",  OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = p.Name;
command.Parameters.Add("@param3",  OleDbType.Date).Value = p.DateFrom;
command.Parameters.Add("@param4",  OleDbType.Date).Value = p.DateTo;
command.Parameters.Add("@param5",  OleDbType.Boolean).Value = bool.Parse(p.Internet.ToString());
command.Parameters.Add("@param6",  OleDbType.Boolean).Value = bool.Parse(p.Telephone.ToString());
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: May need to add tryparse, unless you know the data is clean?