# what do i write into c# to edit the data in an access database

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I have an access database that I created using sql in the actual program and have used a 'BIT' to make a record true or false. Now I would like to use the update sql statement to change whether my record is true or false.

For example I have a payments database table and a paid record which is either true or false.

```cs
if (HasPaidCBOX.Checked)
{
    Cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Payments SET Paid = @p WHERE PlayerID ='" + PaymentForm.ID + "'";
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", xxx);
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I would like to know what goes in the place marked with three x's.

Comment: Did `true` not work?

Comment: Also, you should be parameterising _both_ values there, not just xxx. PaymentForm.ID should be parameterised too.

Comment: Access uses `-1` for TRUE, so try `-1`

Comment: @OlivierRogier This question has nothing to do with SQL injection (even though it happens to contain that vulnerability, the OP isn't asking about it). As such, not a duplicate.

Comment: @TheMixy [you are right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073357/how-to-insert-bool-into-database) `-1` should work

Comment: @TheMixy thank you it worked what is the number for false or an unchecked box?

Comment: @OlivierRogier Absolutely, I agree, that link may help with the slighty off-topic injection problem, but not merits a close-vote for that reason.

Comment: @Jack Ferdinand I posted an answer below. Please accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access uses `-1` for TRUE and `0` for FALSE. So use `0` and `-1`.

Also, as pointet out by @ADyson you should parameterise all values in your SQL statements.